# How to search for a specific keyword in multiple XML files

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, data-analysis, text-mining

I have to analyze multiple XML-files (> 1000 files).

One tag in these XML-files contains free text.
I need to search for a specific keyword in this tag e.g. 'Example'
and save the output (Name of file, free text/tag) in a CSV.

I tried something like this (I am a newbie in Python..everyone starts small).

```
import os
import os.path

for fname in os.listdir('C:/Testpath/xml'):
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        f = open(fname)
        if 'Example' in f.read():
            print(fname)
        f.close()
```

But this doesn´t seem to work, since the only output I get is a XML file which doesn´t contain the specified keyword. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for fname in os.listdir('C:/Testpath/xml'):
    if fname.endswith('.xml'):
        with open fname as f:
            tr = ET.parse(f)
            for e in tr.iter():
                if 'Example' in fname:
                    print(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, you need to install this package: pip install simplified_scrapy

It might be better if you could give an example of XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
files = utils.getSubFile('C:/Testpath/xml', end='.xml')
rows = []
keywordReg = '(word1)|(word2)'
for f in files:
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(utils.getFileContent(f))
    node = doc.getElementByReg(keywordReg)
    if node:
        rows.append([f, node.tag, node.text])

utils.save2csv('test.csv', rows, newline='')
```

[Here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples) are more examples. This lib is easy to use.